# How did the Beast have a child?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood

According to *Torchwood*, [Abaddon](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Abaddon) is the son of [the Beast](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Beast_(The_Impossible_Planet)).

[image: He has your fangs!]

However, according to *Doctor Who*, the Beast has been imprisoned since before the creation of the universe.

Is Abaddon also older than the universe, or did the Beast manage to sire him while imprisoned? If so, do we know how?

Comment: Abaddon must take after his mother, who I assume was some sort of mastiff.

Comment: "*The Dark One and all the Forsaken are bound in Shayol Ghul, bound by the Creator at the moment of Creation, bound until the end of time.*"

Comment: When a mummy beast and a daddy beast love each other very much....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking into account the wibbly-wobbly nature of time and the wibbly-wobbly nature of the *Doctor Who* canon, it's worth noting that according to the BBC webcomic "[The Beast is Back in Town](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Beast_Is_Back_In_Town_(comic_story))" the Beast wasn't actually destroyed by the black hole, but simply flung back in time to the 20th Century. On arrival, he takes control of the TARDIS with the laughably simple plan of **ruling the universe**.

[image: BBC Webcomic]

At some point in his jaunts through space and time, it seems that he found the time to settle down and raise a family, meeting a nice lady-beast and siring a wee little beastling of his very own.

Comment: Man, that webcomic looks... really terrible. But still official, I guess, so +1.

Comment: @roguejedi - Yeah, these were pretty dire even by the BBC's low standards.

Answer (score -4):

It's not meant to be taken literally. These are metaphysical entities. They don't require intercourse.

Abaddon is just another physical form that evil takes to mess with the corporeal world.

Abaddon is called "Son" because it is an extension or metaphysical part of The Devil.

Comment: You could improve this answer by citing some evidence to support these assertions.

Comment: This is like asking me to provide you physical evidence that God exists.

Comment: So your answer is equivalent to a claim that God exists? I.e. something which is totally unprovable, and a matter of personal faith? If so, then it's a poor answer by the standards of this site. You should only post an answer if you can cite some evidence from an official source to back it up, be it some dialogue, narration, or an image from the story itself, or a statement from one of the creators involved. If you have nothing like that, and you merely wish to express your own personal feelings about something, then it may be worthwhile posting those as a comment, but not as an answer.

Comment: You do realize that this is literature, right? This is not science. And Christianity has had a huge influence on the western culture.

Comment: This doesn't negate the fundamental principle that answers should be based as much as possible on tangible evidence, rather than guesses. Examining evidence is how we distinguish between truths and falsehoods, and that principle is just as relevant when discussing literature as anything else.

Comment: “You do realize that this is literature, right?” Presumably you do too? When we say “evidence”, we mean from the work of literature being asked about, or its authors. (If you think this bit of Doctor Who was based on stuff from Christianity, describing that stuff in more detail would also be great.)

Comment: It literally says who the Beast is in Dr. Who and the names it goes by.